# How to copy/paste with the TigerVNC screen scraping server?

Tags: vnc, tigervnc

I have the TigerVNC screen scraping server installed so that I can server up the actual display session to other computers. My windows client is the latest TigerVNC viewer. All is working well enough, though I don't seem to be able to copy and paste between the client and server. Is there a way to enable this functionality?